# Cannot fetch rooms through EWS API

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I always get an empty response when I try to use the `GetRoomLists` web-service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn643730%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_GetRoomListewsma

However, with the same account, I can correctly see rooms when I am using Outlook.
If I watch the network activity when I use Outlook, I can see that roughly 3 calls are made:

1. `GetRoomLists` is called and an empty result is returned
2. `GetRoomsInternal` is called and this time rooms are correctly being returned
3. `GetUserAvailabilityInternal` enables to fetch the availability of each rooms returned by `GetRoomsInternal`

It looks like `GetRoomsInternal` and `GetUserAvailabilityInternal` are exactly the API I want to call. Besides, these  API seem to be private since they are not documented.

Is there a way to fetch all rooms using the public API ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006063/cannot-retrieve-any-room-list-from-exchg-2013-with-c-sharp/31007695#31007695.

Comment: Thank you, I can successfully fetch rooms. I now need to get the room details!